# Evaluate the expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions, rational-numbers

Evaluate the expression

$$\frac{1^2}{1^2-10+50}+\frac{2^2}{2^2-20+50}+\cdots+\frac{80^2}{80^2-80+50}$$

What should I do after that ?

$\sum\frac{n^2}{n^2-10n+50}$

I'm not seeing anything to find some way to cancel out the terms or something like that !

Comment: Should the $-80$ in the last be $-800?$

Comment: No ! I checked it out again and it's 80.

Comment: Then your general term doesn't match the last explicit one you give. Where did you get this expression from?

Comment: Then, the book, or the formula is wrong. (or the series is inconsistent.)

Comment: Assume it's $800$ and move on?

Comment: The sum can be rewritten as $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{k^2-10k+50}\quad=\quad n+5\bigg[\Big(H_{n-5+5i}+H_{n-5-5i}\Big)-\Big(H_{-5+5i}+H_{-5-5i}\Big)\bigg]$$ where $H_a$ is the generalized [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by approximating the sum by an integral:
$$
\int_0^n \frac{x^2}{x^2-10x+50}\,dx
$$
Mathematica says the integral is
$$
n-5\ln 50+5\ln(50-10n+n^2)
$$
although I can't tell you why. (see first comment below, thanks @Tim Ratigan)
For $n=80$, this evaluates to $80+\ln 18424351793=103.637$. This is only an approximation that is useful for large $n$. For $n=80$, the sum itself is $104.203$.

**EDIT**
The general formula you posted is
$$
\frac{n^2}{n^2-10n+50}
$$
When $n=80$, substituting $n$ for $80$ gives
$$\frac{80^2}{80^2-80\cdot 10+80}=\frac{80^2}{80^2-800+50}$$
For $n=8$, this does give $-80$ in the denominator, but then, you won't have an $80^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: $$\begin{align} \frac{n^2}{n^2-10n+50}&=\frac{n^2}{(n-5)^2+5^2}\\
&=\frac{((n-5)+5)^2}{(n-5)^2+5^2}\\
&=1+5\frac{2(n-5)}{n^2-10n+50}\\
&=\frac{\text d}{\text dn}\left(n+5\log(n^2-10n+50)\right) \end{align}$$
So $$ \int_0^n \frac{x^2}{x^2-10x+50}\text dx=\left.x+5\log(x^2-10x+50)\right|_0^n=n+5\log(n^2-10n+50)-5\log 50 $$

Comment: What would happen if the last term was 800 ? I meant how would I solve the problem ?

Comment: This solution assumes the last term is $800$, because the general formula says $-10n$ and for $n=80$, this is $-800$.

Comment: Do you have some link or source explaining that ?

Comment: Explaining what exactly?

Comment: This such general formula. I don't understand yet why 10n ? And if n = 8, this is 80.

Comment: Because n=80, not 8.