# A finite sum with an unusual pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

$\frac{1^2}{1^2-10+50}+\frac{2^2}{2^2-20+50}+...+\frac{9^2}{9^2-90+50}$

I tried to open all the terms but to no avail . I would be grateful if someone could help me .

Comment: Is that a series or a (finite) sum with 9 terms?

Comment: finite sum with 9 terms

Comment: 1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616936/evaluate-the-expression?noredirect=1   2) https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1891417p12907746

Comment: The assignment from which i got this question doesn't require calculus

Comment: Check the second link...exact qsn.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: "I tried to open all the terms but to no avail" : What does this mean?  For example, do you understand why the 1st term in the series equals $$\frac{1}{41} ~?$$  If so, couldn't you use a pocket or online calculator to  convert each of the $9$ terms to fractions of the form $~\displaystyle \frac{A}{B} ~: A,B \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ find the least common multiples (or **any** common multiples) of the denominators, and then sum all $9$ terms?

Comment: I know i could do that way but that is not how the sum is to be solved ,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All roads lead to Rome. Merely writing out the terms gives us:

$\frac{1}{41} + \frac{4}{34} + \frac{9}{29} + \frac{16}{26} + \frac{25}{25}+ \frac{36}{26} + \frac{49}{29} + \frac{64}{34} + \frac{81}{41}$

Start adding the first term and last term and so on going in gives us:

$2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1= 9$